# removing a space from a string by awk

Tags: awk

How can I remove a space located between name and lastname from a string by using awk?
most of the examples are about redirecting data from command line to awk but I need to manipulate a string inside an awk script.

Convert this:

```
"steve john"
```

to:

```
"stevejohn"
```

I have a string variable which I asked user to input inside an awk script. I need to remove the spaces.

Comment: `awk '{print $1 $2}' filename` OR `echo "hi gh"| awk '{print $1 $2}'`

Comment: If you have an answer about building shell scripts, please edit your question to include what you have tried.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

`gsub` is your friend. The following command basically does a global substitution of a regular expression (a single space in this case), replacing it with an empty string, on the target `$0` (the whole line).

```
pax> echo "steve john" | awk '{ gsub (" ", "", $0); print}'
stevejohn
```

You can use any target, including one input by a user:

```
pax> awk 'BEGIN {getline xyzzy ; gsub(" ","", xyzzy) ; print xyzzy}'
hello there my name is pax
hellotheremynameispax
```

Answer (score 7):

Use `sed`:

```
$ echo "steve john" | sed 's/ //g'
stevejohn
```

If you must use `awk`, do this:

```
$ echo "steve john" | gawk '{print $1 $2}'
stevejohn
```

**Edit:**

Inside a bash script, you can do this:

```
s="steve john" # user input
t=$(echo $s | gawk '{print $1 $2}')
echo $t
```

Comment: I have a string variable which I asked user to input inside an awk script. I need to remove the spaces

Comment: remember to quote your variables ( "$s" not $s ) and you wouldn't really call an external command to do that in bash, you'd use the shell builtins:  s="steve john"; echo "${s// }"
stevejohn

Answer (score 1):

```
echo "john smith aaa " |\
awk 'BEGIN {FS=" "; OFS=""} {for(i=1;i<=NF;++i) {out = out OFS $i}} END {print out;}'
```

Comment: or you can use "sed" command. sed is commonly used to remove or replace strings from input.

Comment: awk is usually a tiny bit faster, though :)