# Using awk to remove spaces from a field

Tags: awk, gsub

In searching for my answer I came across this:

[removing a space from a string by awk](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12910468/removing-a-space-from-a-string-by-awk)

but I was unsuccessful in extrapolating the information here to my situation.

I currently have some data formatted like this:

```
Host Name="Host Name Here"
Product Name="Product Name Here"
Program Name="Program Name Here"
```

I simply want to remove the spaces in the first field, so the result will look like this:

```
HostName="Host Name Here"
ProductName="Product Name Here"
ProgramName="Program Name Here"
```

Using this code resulted in removing all spaces from all fields:

```
awk 'BEGIN {FS=" "; OFS=""} {for(i=1;i<=NF;++i) {out = out OFS $i}} END {print out;}'
```

Which, to my understanding, is just looking for spaces as a field separator and printing out, with spaces replaced by empty strings, which isn't quite what I want.

I believe I need to use awk, and I'll have to set the Field Separator to =, and then apply something like this, maybe??

```
awk '$1 ~ /[ \t]/ {gsub(/[ \t]/,"",$1)1}
```

Which, to my very limited understanding, will look at field 1, and if it contains the pattern [ \t], will use gsub to replace that space with an empty string. I don't think I have the syntax entirely correct here, though.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use `=` as the field separator (for both input and output) and remove blanks from the first field:

```
awk -F= -v OFS="=" '{gsub(/[[:blank:]]/, "", $1); print}' << END
Host Name="Host Name Here"
Product Name="Product Name Here"
The Program Name="Program Name Here"
END
```

```
HostName="Host Name Here"
ProductName="Product Name Here"
TheProgramName="Program Name Here"
```

Comment: This is exactly where my attempt was trying to get to. Glad to know I was pretty close, at least.

Answer (score 3):

The simplest way to this if you only have single spaces would be with `sed`:

```
$ sed 's/ //' file
HostName="Host Name Here"
ProductName="Product Name Here"
ProgramName="Program Name Here"
```

With `GNU sed` you can use the `-i` option to store the changes back to the file:

```
$ sed -i 's/ //' file
```

---

If it may be the case that you may have more than two words separated by a space before the `=` you could do the following with `awk`:

```
$ awk '{sub(/ /,"",$1)}1' FS="=" OFS="=" file
HostName="Host Name Here"
ProductName="Product Name Here"
ProgramName="Program Name Here"
```

Comment: Thanks. This works. I don't understand why this sed command isn't going through the whole line and replacing all the spaces though.

Comment: This will fail for a first field with several spaces. And it will be difficutl for `sed` to fix it.

Comment: On further inspection, Birei is right. I've also noticed weird behavior for the very first line it executes on...

Comment: @Birei good point, didn't think of that, doesn't seem to be the case but added a solution any how. @dsclough that is `sed` default behaviour to remove all occurences you would use the `g` flag *(global)*.

Comment: @sudo_O: Yes. I will you a **+1** for the fast `awk` fix. I thought in it at first sight. It seems much more natural and appropiate in this case.

Answer (score 0):

```
awk '{print $1$2,$3,$4}' file
HostName="Host Name Here"
ProductName="Product Name Here"
ProgramName="Program Name Here"
```